# Any differences with %.1f and %.01f?

Tags: c, floating-point, format

When i compiles a program with this code:

```
int main()
{
  float a;

  scanf("%f", &a);

  printf("%.1f\n", a); //Here

  return 0;
}
```

There is no difference with this other:

```
int main()
{
  float a;

  scanf("%f", &a);

  printf("%.01f\n", a); //Here

  return 0;
}
```

Anybody can tell me why?

Comment: I'd start with the specifics of the format string and particularly the section on float-formatting, precision, and alignment [at this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Thank you so much i'll be reading the information you gave me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number behind the period is the precision that specifies the number of digits after the decimal point of a floating-point value. The leading zero has no meanings.

The number before the period is the number that specifies the minimum field width. The leading zero will change the padding character from white space to 0.

Answer (score 2):

The digits after the decimal point specify the precision - the minimum number of digits which will be written. .1 and .01 both say to put at least 1 digit, and to pad the result with zeros if there is fewer than 1 digit.  Plain `%f` is equivalent to `%.6f`, i.e. 6 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score -2):

the output of first program will be for eg. a=100
for the both print command it would be 
100.000000 (by default presicion of double is 6)
100.0 
only.
where as the second program will have the value:
100.000000 (by default presicion of double)
100.0

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! I find your answer hard to read, maybe you could rewrite it so the meaning is clearer? The question is also very old, have you checked that your answer provides anything new that other answers doesn't?